# unable to run c++ program in sublime text 3(build system works!!!)

Tags: c++, sublimetext3, build-system

I am trying to set up sublime text 3 for compiling and running c++ programs. 
I am on a Windows machine(x64).
My build system looks like this:

```
{
"cmd": ["g++.exe", "-o", "$file_base_name", "$file"],

"variants": [

    {   
        "cmd": ["start", "cmd", "/k", "$file_base_name"],
        "shell": true,
        "name": "Run"

    }
]
}
```

When I choose build, it shows me no error. I can then run the .exe file from the directory.
When I choose build and run option, the problem begins. It shows me:

```
[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: g++ "C:\Users\***\Documents\c++\new.cpp" -o 
"C:\Users\***\Documents\c++/new" && 
"C:\Users\***\Documents\c++/new"] 
[dir: C:\Users\***\Documents\c++]
[path: C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA 
Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Windows\system32;
C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;
C:\Program Files\Python37\Scripts;C:\Program Files `(x86)\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin\;
c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\;
c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\DTS\Binn\;
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin;
C:\TDM-GCC-64\bin;C:\Program Files\mingw-w64\mingw64\bin;]
[Finished]
```

My question is how can I overcome this problem? I am repeating that **MY BUILD SYSTEM WORKS, PROBLEM BEGINS ONLY WHEN I TRY TO RUN THE FILE FROM SUBLIME TEXT**

Comment: Did you try to run your program from terminal with `C:\Users\***\Documents\c++/new`? Did you look into `C:\Users\***\Documents\c++` if there is a program called `new`?

Comment: yes, I tried `cd C:\Users\***\Documents\c++`. Then I typed `start new.exe`. It worked. I double checked that there is a program called new.cpp. But I am unable to run the program directly from the sublime text. I would be glad if you give me the code for new build system by which I will be able to both build and run the program. Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you type `start`? If you need it, then you probably also need it in your script. Try `"cmd": "g++ \"${file}\" -o \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\" && start \"${file_path}/${file_base_name}\""`

Comment: that is not working either. It is giving me the almost same message. `[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd: g++ "C:\Users\***\Documents\c++\sublime.cpp" -o "C:\Users\***\Documents\c++/new" && start "C:\Users\***\Documents\c++/new"]` ..................... so on

Comment: I want my code to do `cd C:\Users\***\Documents\c++` command first. Then `start new.exe`

Comment: Why do you type `start`? Why do you want your code to cd?

Comment: `cd` will navigate to the working directory. then `start` will execute the `.exe` file

Comment: Your error message doesn't fit to your configuration. I don't get the whole thing with `start`. Did you try to use backslashes? Maybe the problem is the slash between `c++` and `new`.

Comment: command executes well without `start`. But I need `cd C:\Users\***\Documents\c++` and then `new.exe` command

Comment: I don't understand the problem. If the command executes without `start` why do you use it? Why do you need `cd`?